# Select between two months

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a select query where my OrderDate is between two months.
this is my code so far.

```
declare @FromMonth datetime
declare @ToMonth datetime
set @FromMonth = '20111201'
set @ToMonth = '20120301'

select *
from Order o
where o.OrderDate between @FromMonth and @ToMonth
```

This almost works, except that it also looks at the day of month, meaning in this example that it won't select all the days' in my @ToMonth

I'm using Sql Server 2012

EDIT

Just to make it more clear, I don't wanna trust my @FromMonth and @ToMonth input to know the last day in the month. The above is just a sample to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Have you tried this ? -> set @ToMonth = '20120331'

Comment: it is because your datetime has a date and you don't specify you only want the BETWEEN to care about year and month.. try to use MONTH() and YEAR() functions, or set your ToMonth to the last day of the month

Comment: @OriesokVlassky - No, really, please don't do this.  It will destroy the ability to use an INDEX SEEK and will yield a full scan.  Don't wrap search-fields in functions if you want any kind of decent performance.

Comment: @gulbaek - In your edit you say you don't want to trust your inputs. See @Nikola's answer for using DATEADD/DATEDIFF to round values to the beginning of the months, so that you can use them in `>=` and `<`.  You may decide to sanitise you inputs slightly differently, but if you can understand that answer, then you should be well on your way to being able to sanitise the inputs however you like :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`between` rarely works as well as you might hope, I usually find it better to write the range as an inclusive/exclusive pair and apply appropriate comparisons:

```
declare @FromMonth datetime
declare @ToMonth datetime
set @FromMonth = '20111201'
set @ToMonth = '20120401'

select *
from Order o
where o.OrderDate >= @FromMonth and o.OrderDate < @ToMonth
```

This will also avoid nastiness if `OrderDate` includes a time component.

Comment: +1 for pointing the OP to using `< end_point`. DATETIMEs are effectively continuous values, to people should always be using `>= X and < Y`

Comment: Like your simple solution, though I find it a little bit of cheating, that you changed the @ToMonth input, will take a look and see if I can make the rest of my code to work together with it.

Comment: @gulbaek - It's not cheating, it's fixing. Your input is a DATETIME, a *continuous* value. `20120301` doesn't mean "all of march", it means "00:00 on the 1st of March". `BETWEEN` is for discrete values like integers. Use `>=` and `<` for continuous values. If the field was a FLOAT, you wouldn't expect `WHERE my_float BETWEEN 1 AND 2` to include `2.9`. For that you should say `WHERE my_float >= 1 AND my_float < 3`. Equally, in your case, if you wanted exactly one month, your parameters would both be `20120101`, but there is NO time between those values. Using `<` makes this make more sense.

Comment: @gulbaek - If, despite @Dems excellent comment, you still want to have `@ToMonth` be equal to `'20120301'`, you could always replace `@ToMonth` with `DATEADD(month,1,@ToMonth)` in the query.

Answer (score 2):

First dateadd/datediff pair returns first day of month, second returns first day of next month:

```
where o.OrderDate >= dateadd(m, datediff (m, 0, @FromMonth), 0) 
  and o.OrderDate < dateadd(m, datediff (m, 0, @ToMonth) + 1, 0)
```

EDIT: changed my response according to dems' advice.

Comment: And what if the OrderDate has a time part?  Anything after `00:00` on the morning of the last day of the month gets ignored.  See @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer; use `>= and <` for continuous values.  `BETWEEN` should only be used for discrete values.

Comment: +1 as this now works and I don't want it to be sandwiched between wrong asnwers :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your WHERE clause to something like:

```
WHERE (MONTH(o.OrderDate) BETWEEN MONTH(@FromMonth) AND MONTH(@ToMonth))
AND (YEAR(o.OrderDate) BETWEEN YEAR(@FromMonth) AND YEAR(@ToMonth))
```

Comment: This will destroy an chance the optimiser has of using indexes effectively.  To resolve this query takes a full scan, rather than a much much faster seek.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE MONTH(*col name*) between'01' and '05'
```

this will give data b/w Jan to May and *col name* should be DATE COLUMN.